# ImportError: No module named _imagingtk

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I wanted to start using Tkinter with python and have following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

top = Tk()
dir(top)
top.title("Erstes Frame")

erstesFrame = Frame(top, height=250, width=250)
erstesFrame.pack_propagate(0)
erstesFrame.pack()

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("mario.gif"))

erstesBild = Label(erstesFrame, image = img)

erstesBild.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

But when I try to execute it, it just gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ToDoAPP.py", line 14, in <module>
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("mario.gif"))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 116, in __init__
    self.paste(image)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 181, in paste
    import _imagingtk
ImportError: No module named _imagingtk
```

I installed PIL with python-pip and my OS is ubuntu 12.04 and my python version is 2.7.3

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to install [`ImageTk`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagetk.htm) module.

In debian, ubuntu, you can use following command to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install python-imaging-tk
```

**UPDATE**

If you're using recent version of ubuntu (16.04+), the package name changed.

- `python-pil.imagetk` (Python 2.x)
- `python3-pil.imagetk` (Python 3.x)

Comment: Can it be installed via pip?

Comment: I already have that package, Version: 2.6.1-2, and am still getting the error.

Comment: @appas, i suspect you're using non-system version of Python. Otherwise, please post a separated question.

Comment: @falsetru what do you mean by "non-system version"?

Comment: @appas, I meant - system version: Python installed with apt-get/dpkg/yum/rpm/....

Comment: Ok, well my Python is Version: 2.7.9-1, and both that package and `python-imaging-tk` are within package management  (installed via apt). Now this problem is extra strange, because I do not recall updating any of the packages involved between when the application at fault last worked, and now that it yields this error.

Comment: I had to use @SarcasticSully's answer: `sudo apt install python3-pil.imagetk` on my Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

Comment: @MarkHu, Thank you for the comment. I updated the answer after testing in Ubuntu 16.10. I didn't expect package name would change at the time of posting the answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

As noted by falsetru, you need to install the ImageTk module first: it doesn't automatically come with Python. To do this, run one of the commands below:

If you're using Python 2.x, use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-imaging-tk
```

If you're using Python 3.x, use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pil.imagetk
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Sad this hasn't been solved even on new distros like Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the answers here, on Ubuntu 16.04 the package name is slightly different (even for Python 2):

`sudo apt-get install python-pil.imagetk`

Answer (score 0):

The most universal solution is:

```
python -m pip install image
```

Should work for Python 2 and 3 and also for Windows. PIP will install all dependencies.