# How to load a png image with Python 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (32-bit)?

Tags: python, tkinter, png, pip

I download my Python 2.7 with Anaconda. I'm using windows 7.
I tried following:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, Canvas
import ImageTk

t = Tk()
t.title("Transparency")

frame = Frame(t)
frame.pack()

canvas = Canvas(frame, bg="black", width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

photoimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=r"test.png")
canvas.create_image(150, 150, image=photoimage)

t.mainloop()
```

I get following Error:

```
ImportError: No module named _imagingtk
```

I think I need to install ImageTk, how this [ImportError: No module named _imagingtk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788454/importerror-no-module-named-imagingtk/22788542#22788542) says.

But how can I install it on Windows?
Where should I type this code?

```
 $ pip install ImageTk
```

If I try:

```
 import ImageTk
```

I don't get any Error. What means ImageTk is actually already installed, right?

Thanks

Comment: _"Where should I type this code?"_ Into the cmd window.

Comment: @Kevin thanks, what should I type before $ pip install ImageTk into the cmd?

Comment: It seems there is an [open issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6) concerning this matter .

Comment: You may be able to work-around the problem by searching your hard disk for the missing `_imagingtk` module and then appending the directory it's in to the list `sys.path` at the beginning of your script.

Comment: did you get this work?@Hangon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageTk` is defined in the package `PIL` which you should install with:

```
pip install Pillow
```

`Pillow` is a port of `PIL` that is accessible through `pip`. Now import `PIL` like so:

```
from PIL import ImageTk
```