# Python Anaconda no module name _imagingtk

Tags: python, eclipse, anaconda, python-imaging-library

to preface , I've already visited [this issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27692716/how-to-load-a-png-image-with-python-2-7-8-anaconda-2-1-0-32-bit) and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29754143/importerror-cannot-import-name-imagingtk) but none of these solved my problem.

I'm currently on the eclipse environment and am using the anaconda python interpreter in my project. I have this piece of code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
# other imports

# ....
# def initUI(self):
    pic1 = Image.open("pic1.jpg")
    pic1_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pic1)
    label1 = Label(self, image=pic1_img)
    label1.image = pic1_img
    label1.place(x=20, y=20)
```

Now upon running I get this output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\workspace\Tkinter_tutorial\absolutePositioning.py", line 46, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\...\workspace\Tkinter_tutorial\absolutePositioning.py", line 42, in main
    app = Window(root)
  File "C:\Users\...\workspace\Tkinter_tutorial\absolutePositioning.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.initUI()
  File "C:\Users\....\workspace\Tkinter_tutorial\absolutePositioning.py", line 22, in initUI
    pic1_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pic1)
  File "C:\Users\....\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 116, in __init__
    self.paste(image)
  File "C:\Users\....\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 181, in paste
    import _imagingtk
ImportError: No module named _imagingtk
```

I've tried `conda install Pillow` , and the package is marked as already installed. Yet I continue to get this error. I'm running **window 64 bit python 2.7**. Has anyone else encountered this problem, and how can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that you installed _both_ ancient PIL and its modern fork Pillow, and the former is interfering with the latter?

Comment: have you work this out?

Comment: @micmica see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution to this problem, which involves removing the default pillow installation and grabbing an old version of the library.

- First open up a command prompt (with anaconda in your path) and do

  `conda remove PIL` or `conda remove pillow`
- Then install PIL from [here](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) , `PIL-1.1.7.win32-py2.7.exe` . Ensure you install it to *Lib/site-packages*

This worked for me and everyone else using my project that had anaconda installed